# Transformer won't work for US plug

Tags: uk, transformer, adapter, us

I live in the UK but have a few US appliances in my possession which I would like to use here in the UK. To avoid having to rewire all the plugs, I bought a transformer to step down the voltage from 230V to 110V. The outlet is set to receive a European plug, so I bought a Schuko adapter to accept US configured plugs. However, when I plugged it into the transformer, it did not work.

The transformer, I believe, is fine. I will check my appliances further, but I can't decide if the fault is with the adapter, which I only just bought. Does anyone have any thoughts? The transformer can receive a 3 prong plug, but as far as I know, European plugs only have 2 prongs.

The transformer nameplate

[image: Transformer nameplate]

Transformer specs

[image: Transformer specs]

Transformer receptacle

[image: Transformer receptacle]

Adapter interface

[image: Adapter]

Comment: UK 110V plugs tend to be 3 prong with round prongs and in blue plastic. Some pictures of what you are using will help decide what is happening.

Comment: What's the device you're trying to power?  Also, try reversing the plug -- unlike European devices, some (though not many) US devices care about polarity.

Comment: We traveled to Europe and the UK from the US a couple of summers ago. Other than a curling iron and hair dryer, we used all of our US plugged devices with a simple plug adapter and did _not_ use any sort of transformer. Most modern devices, especially electronics, will accept 110v -240v and work just fine. Are you sure you _need_ the transformer? Check the labels on your appliances.

Comment: Can you add pictures of what exactly you have?

Comment: Yes, can you add photos of the *nameplate* labels for all the things involved here?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, but you have to evaluate that appliance by appliance.   OP, do you have a voltmeter?

Comment: I have added the transformer nameplate. I am trying to power a 900W vacuum cleaner - that’s the highest wattage appliance anyway.

Comment: Just to add, I tried charging my phone using the 110V transformer and it won't do it. The phone has, in the past, been able to charge using both 110V and 230V. So there's likely nothing wrong with the vacuum cleaner that I tried plugging into the transformer. Physical form and fit with regards to the adapter don't throw up a problem - in other words, the adapter fits into the socket of the transformer just fine and the plugs fit into the adapter. Let me know if there is anything I've said that isn't clear.

Comment: Can you post a photo showing the pin configuration of the receptacle on the transformer? I suspect you may have the wrong adapter given that this is a worksite transformer with a significant IP rating...

Comment: Also keep in mind that a transformer will **not** change frequency. For a lot of devices that doesn't matter. For lots of things with motors, **like vacuum cleaners**, that matters a lot. A ~20% difference in speed can have some serious effects.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I think you may have a point. The transformer has a three pin configuration while my adaptor is only 2 pin. I could not find any three pin adaptors, to be honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Wrong adapter

Your problem is basically entirely that you have the wrong adapter.  Your transformer is a UK worksite transformer that outputs two 55V legs with an inaccessible center-tap for the grounded neutral, and thus uses IEC 60309 *pin and sleeve* (also known as "CEEform" or "Commando" in the UK) type connectors as they are rugged and weather-resistant.  These are *not* intended to mate with the Schuko plug on your current adapter, though, so you'll need to get or fabricate (using a short length of appropriate cordage as a go-between) an adapter from the appropriate pin-and-sleeve plug to a NEMA 5-15 cord cap and use that instead.

Comment: Will a US device looking for one  110 (120) V leg work on this transformer then if it outputs 2 55 V legs?

Comment: @PhilippNagel -- unless it really, really cares about having a grounded neutral, it'll be fine

Answer (score 2):

The socket on the transformer is a "CEEform" or "Commando" socket (they are two names for the same thing).  It's a widely used international standard, but is completely incompatible with the standard German or French plugs.

You would need to buy or make an appropriate adaptor to fit your US plugs.  Or take off the US plugs and fit CEEform ones instead.

Note that yellow plugs/sockets are specifically intended for 110V.  Other colour plugs will not fit, even if they are the same size.